# How to get some value of an array with range in iOS swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, range

I  have and array like this:

```
let array:Array<String> = ["name0","name1","name2","name3","name4","name5","name6"]
```

And now I wanna get

> name0 , name1 , name2

. 
How to do this?

Comment: `array[0 ... 2]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a slice using `array[0 ... 2]` or `array[0 ..< 3]` or `array[..<3]`.

To convert it into a new array, you have to:

```
Array(array[0 ... 2])
```

but many operations can be done on the subsequence.

Comment: Ambiguous subscript with base type 'Array<String>' and index type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'

Comment: dataSourceArr:Array<String> = array[0 ..< 3]

Comment: I set result in another array contains string value

Comment: @reza_khalafi The result you get is an `ArraySlice`, lose the `:Array<String>`. If you want to convert to an array, you have to wrap the result in `Array(...)` as I said in my answer. Also, please use the short type specifiers, e.g. `[String]` instead of `Array<String>`.

Comment: like this:   let dataSourceArr:Array[String] = array[0 ..< 3]        ?

Comment: @reza_khalafi Nope, `let dataSourceArr: [String] = Array(array[0 ..< 3])` or just `let dataSourceArr = Array(array[0 ..< 3])`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to get slice of an array :

```
let values = array[0...2]
```

Here you will know what else you can do : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice